# Parse SOAP response from XML file into object

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a project with a working SOAP integration and I need to write some tests.

To avoid making making web service calls during tests, I saved some SOAP responses into XML files, but I don't know how to turn these XML into the appropriate objects.

I've tried using `JAXBContext` / `Unmarshaller`, but I get the error `expected elements are (None)`, which I believe is related to the fact that the class associated with the XML response doesn't have a `@XmlRootElement` annotation (and I can't change this).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768898/unmarshalling-soap-envelope-from-file-in-java?rq=1) is very similar to mine, but the current answer doesn't really specify how to get the final object from the response.

It's also not clear to me if I have to leave the SOAP-specific tags or if it's easier to strip them and treat the file as a normal XML.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998627) I got it working.

The problem was the missing `@XmlRootElement` as expected and in order to make it work the 2-parameter version of `unmarshall()` should be used as below (code from the other question):

```
String pathname = "file.xml";
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(pathname); 
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(UserType.class); 
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller(); 
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); 
XMLEventReader someSource = factory.createXMLEventReader(stream); 
JAXBElement<UserType> userElement = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(someSource, UserType.class); UserType user = userElement.getValue();
```